# An integral domain with a quotient field K, then...

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

This question was asked in my quiz on module theory and I need help in solving it:

> Let A be an integral domain with quotient field K. Then :

(a) If V is a torsion module over A, then $Hom_A(V,A) = 0$.

(b) $Hom_A(K;A) \neq 0 $ if and only if A = K.

(c) If K is an A-submodule of an arbitrary direct sum of finite A-modules, then A = K.

I have done (a).

Attempt for (b): Let A=K , I assumed that $Hom_A(K,A)=0$  which implies that for each f $ :  K \to A=K$, f(a)=0 for all a but I am unable to get a contradiction.

Conversaly, if $Hom_A(K,A)\neq 0$ it means that there exists an $f: K \to A$ and atleast one $k\in $ such that $f(k)\neq 0$,but unable to proceed.

I am unable to use the fact that A is integral domain with quotient field K.

Also, for (c) I have no thoughts.

So, can you please help. Kindly consider giving  some hints.

Answer (score 1):

For (b). Let $f\in\text{Hom}_A(K,A)$ be nonzero, then necessarily $f(1_K)=1_A$. Any element in $K$ is of the form $a/b$ with $a,b\in A$ and $b\neq 0$. Therefore if $b\neq 0$ then $bf(1/b)=f(b/b)=f(1_K)=1_A$, so every nonzero element in $A$ is invertible. This shows $A=K$. In particular $\text{Hom}_A(K,A)\neq 0$ if and only if $K=A$.

For (c). Take any element $b\neq 0$ in $A$ and write $1/b=m_1+\dots+m_r$ for $m_i\in M_i$ where $K\leq_A M_1\oplus\dots\oplus M_r$. Then from here get an expression for $1_A$ as a sum of elements of $M_i$. Can you finish the argument from here?

Comment: in (b), How does A=K implies that $Hom_A( K,A)=0  iff K=A?

Comment: In (c) , I think I can write $1_A = b(m_1+ ...+m_r)$ , but I am not able to finish the argument. Can you please help?

Comment: @No-One. That was a typo in (b) I meant to write $\text{Hom}_A(K,A)\neq 0$ iff $K=A$. Does it make sense now? The proof I wrote shows the implication from left to right, the implication from right to left is trivial because $A=K$ so the identity map in $K$ is in $\text{Hom}_K(K,K)$.

Comment: can you please help for (c) also?

Comment: ya, (b) is clear now. Thanks!